# Trying to get my navbar to stick to the top of the page and scroll with it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know how to use `position: fixed;` to get it to scroll with the page but my navbar is not at the top of the page it is under my header. I would like the navbar to remain directly under the header until the top of the page hits it then I want it to scroll down with the page. I have tried using JS to do this and using JSfiddle I am able to get it working http://jsfiddle.net/uaqh018d/78/

However, when I apply this to my site it does not work and I can't figure out why.

site code to follow:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<!--begin header & navbar-->

<div class="header">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="banner">
                <h1><img src="media/CSG%20header%20final.svg" width="961" height="250" alt="crit strike gaming header"></h1>                    
            </div>

            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>    
                    <li><a href="#">Previews</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lets Plays</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>                         
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>      
   </div>

   <!--end header & navbar-->       

   <!-- begin content-->    

   <div class="container">  

    <div class="content">


    </div>

   </div>

   <!--end content-->

   <script type="text/javascript" src="navfunction.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background: #ffda0a;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.container{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
}

.content{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 1px;
    clear: both;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffda0a;
}

li{
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 75px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.nav{
    background: #a71e1f;
    width: 960px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 1px;   
}

.nav.fixed {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.banner{
    height: 230px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var distanceFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (distanceFromTop >= $('#header').height())
    {
        $('#nav').addClass('fixed');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#nav').removeClass('fixed');
    }
    });
    });
```

If anyone can figure out the issue I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you forget to include jQuery? You're using jQuery 2.1.0 in the JSFiddle you referenced, but I don't see it in your markup.

Comment: Yeah I am, just did a quick copy/paste of my code and must have missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the corrected fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/drecodeam/8Lubmkvw/

You were using classes in the HTML but accessing them as ID in jQuery.

Corrected JS should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var distanceFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        if (distanceFromTop >= $('.header').height()) {
            $('.nav').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $('.nav').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```